# Wicket and third party connection pool implementations

Tags: java, wicket, connection-pooling

How are we supposed to structure a Wicket application that utilizes a 3rd party connection pool? (e.g. BoneCP, c3P0, HikariCP). In the past, assuming the web app will be deployed on Apache Tomcat, we would just use the default Tomcat pool via JNDI.

Considering that:

1. The library i'm currently looking at (HikariCP) doesn't have an
   explicit support for Tomcat/JNDI ([link to issue](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/8)),
2. and the method to setup JNDI itself varies between application servers
   (let's say Tomcat vs Jetty, i spent last weekend trying to make
   jetty JNDI lookup work, and gave up)

Is there a cross-application-server way to setup connection pool in Wicket apps? 
Back in JSP days I would probably make the Pool object a singleton member in the Application class, would this work (or recommended) in Wicket?

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {
  //
  private SomePoolObject poolInstance; 
  //
  public static Connection getConnection() {
     if (poolInstance == null) {
        poolInstance = ...; //create pool 
     }  
     return poolInstance.getConnection(); 
  } 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never used Wicket, but it seems it comes with Jetty embedded.  This link: [http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource#Pooling_DataSources](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource#Pooling_DataSources) seems to indicate how to setup JNDI DataSources in Jetty.  Is the issue then getting Wicket to use JNDI to pick it up?

Comment: Wicket can be deployed to any Servlet Container, so jetty is not a requirement. Problem is that each container will have different ways to setup the JNDI+connectionpool, so i was wondering if the approach outlined in my post is workable for wicket apps, (the advantage would be that) so i don't have to worry if i have to move to a different container somewhere down the road.

Comment: I think the above approach would be valid.  But I also suspect that some users could be surprised if they've configured a DataSource through their application server's standard mechanism (where "standard" is actually proprietary to that platform) and it was not picked up by your application.  Though loading the pool configuration from a properties file, rather than hardcoding it in the application might ease that somewhat.